# What does it mean arrow in editor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: Eclipse editor:]

Sometimes appears this arrow so I cannot see if breakpoint is installed. Does it possible with some shortcut remove this arrow?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the yellow arrow is the search results icon.  It know it sounds silly :/.  You should just be able to close the search pane and the arrow will go.  Does that fix it?

Comment: This doesn't fix it. I didn't search. Previously I made edit.

Comment: Right.  I'm still thinking it could be a search that was performed at some point.  Just turn off the search arrow all together: General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations preference page

Answer (score 3):

The arrow will go away if you close the search result, not the search view. If you press the X or XX on the search view, it will hide/remove the yellow arrow.

Answer (score 2):

On Eclipse `Help` --> `Help Contents` --> Search `icons`.

Select the `Editor area marker` link, and you will see that the yellow icon is the "Search Result" icon. Whenever you do a search and the result is found, the icon shows which line it found it in.

Answer (score 2):

`Window | Show View | Search` Click Xx icon in the Search view. Clearing the search will remove the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

We have another way to check if any break point is installed at a line without masking arrow icon. It's just hovering mouse over arrow icon, Eclipse will display a popup to claim what are set (include break point) at this line.

Comment: Alternatively, <Alt-Shift-q> then <b> will either open or bring-to-front the **Breakpoints** view.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to clear the arrow is to:

1. Locate the **Show Previous Searches** icon on the *Search pane's* toolbar (looks like a *flashlight-with-document icon that has an attached Dropdown arrow*)
2. Click on that icon's **Dropdown** arrow
3. Select the **Clear History** menu item

This will clear your search history for the current session and remove all the yellow arrows in the editor without having to close the search tab completely.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clear the arrow (without turning them off entirely) is to simply perform another search.

I tried other approaches (closing the search pane, closing the file) and nothing worked.